# convert curl get to rest api to python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, pagerduty

I have this curl command:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2' --header 'Authorization: Token token=y_NbAkKc66ryYTWUXYEu' 'https://api.pagerduty.com/services?time_zone=UTC&sort_by=name'
```

I need to convert it to python using `requests` library

```
import requests

def support(self): 
    services_list = requests.get('I need to convert the link to pass it here as a parameter')
```

Comment: https://curl.trillworks.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests

def support():
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2',
        'Authorization': 'Token token=y_NbAkKc66ryYTWUXYEu'}

    payloads = (
        ('time_zone', 'UTC'),
        ('sort_by', 'name'),)

    services_list = requests.get('https://api.pagerduty.com/services', headers=headers, params=payloads)
```